# Sendgrid php : send email in both text/plain and html

Tags: php, html, email, utf-8, sendgrid

I use the Sendgrid PHP API and would like to send emails in both text/plain and text/html,

**I tried :**

```
$request_body = json_decode('{
    "content": [
       {
          "type": "text/plain", 
          "value": "text version"
       },
       {
          "type": "text/html", 
          "value": "html version"
       }
     ], 
     "subject": "blabla €",
     ...
  }');

  $response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($request_body);
```

**Result :**

- no error are generated by Sendgrid.
- the subject becomes "blabla â‚¬" (if only text/html, the subject received is fine "blabla €")
- and I receive an email with only this content-type :

> Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

**Result expected :**

I would like to send an email simply with 2 content types :

> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

and

> Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

is it possible ? Any idea ?

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: I have yet to get this to work either

Comment: does encoding the subject yourself works? check [this](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/issues/162#issuecomment-228845913). 
It used to happen in the Java library as well but they fixed [it](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-java/issues/139)